# Fill Dictionary(2) with keys to match Dictionary(1)

Tags: c#, .net, csv, dictionary

I did find [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0eedf56a-c769-4806-b2d2-0d452a152f26/fill-empty-values-in-dictionary?forum=csharpgeneral) however I have been unsuccessful at converting this from adding Date-Time to adding empty int keys.

---

I have 2 Dictionaries. I am using one as the "header" row for a csv, and the second for each "data" row.

The idea is that regardless of the format of the information, I can look at the index (key value) of the header for the appropriate cell, and place the value into the appropriate location.

So, for example, File A has an "Name" field, and File B has an "Age" field. It scans File A, and adds `0, "Name"`, to the headerDictionary, then scans File B, and adds `1, "Age"`.

This is where my problem starts:

It then looks for the values of each file. It finds the value for "Name" in File A, refers to the headerDictionary to retrieve the key, and adds `0, "Bob"`. This then is ready to be written to the csv. It goes through the same process for File B, and adds `1, "23"`, to be written to the csv.

My issue is that if I fill in the csv using this information, my csv would still look like:

```
Name,Age
Bob
23
```

So I need to fill in the blanks, and also re-order the dictionary so that each record is filled in appropriately.

```
// Add empty entries to recordDictionary, based on the headerDictionary

// recordDictionary for File A:
 [0, "Bob"]
 [1, ""]

// recordDictionary for File B:
 [0, ""]
 [1, "23"]
```

So then my csv will look like:

```
Name,Age
Bob,
,23
```

Comment: Is the last text box your expected output?

Comment: And do you have one header dictionary, and multiple record dictionaries (one for each "file")?

Comment: @Monty yes, and yes. The "record" dictionary is re-created for each new file, so as to avoid building a "matrix".

Comment: so then for each "file", you'll need to go through each key in the header dictionary: if it's not in the record dictionary, just put a comma, if it is, output the value and a comma. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @monty yup. That's it. I just want to make sure that each entry is in the appropriate location, because 1 file may have both "fields", but in a different order (i.e. "Age", "Name"). Hance why I'm using the indexes, so I can re-order them if necessary.

Comment: So, when do you build your header dictionary? Do you have to go through all your files first? or a representative few? Do you then plan on doing a second pass of the data to create, and output, each record row?

Comment: @monty each file has the potential for more headers. So each file is scanned for both header, and data. If the file does not have any new headers, nothing is added, and the data is just added to the appropriate location

Comment: Have added an answer to your specific question, but tbh this sounds like a DataTable solution would be best.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171735/discussion-between-ben-and-monty).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Edit 4: Answer title question for future visitors]

```
//after you've filled your record dictionary from file...
foreach(int i in headers.Keys) {
    if (!singleRecord.ContainsKey(i)) {
        singleRecord.Add(i, "");
    }
}
```

[Original]

```
var headers = new SortedDictionary<int, string>();
//...populate headers dictionary
var singleRecord = new Dictionary<int, string>();
//...populate a record
var sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach(int i in headers.Keys) {
    sb.Append((singleRecord.ContainsKey(i) ? singleRecord[i] : "") + ",");
}
```

And either remove that trailing comma, or only add it in when needed.

[Edit 1] Although, that answers your specific question, I think it'd be easier to just store the headers as a list, and the keys in your singleRecord Dictionary would just be the actual header strings.

[Edit 2] And personally, I'd suggest simply building a DataTable. You can add extra columns whenever you hit a new header in a file and just add an empty string as a default. Then I'd use a wee function that converts any DataTable to csv.

[Edit 3] Here's the pseudocode (from chat discussion of problem)

```
create new DataTable
for each folder
    for each file
        create new DataRow
        for each label
            if data.Columns not yet with name label
                create new column, default value ""
            add value to row
        add row to DataTable
output DataTable as csv file, or string. //(build yourself a Utility to do this... it's a pretty common thing to want to do)
```